# Preg_replace for url and links

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Right now
I'm using

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?((/[\w/_\.%\-+~]*)?(\?\S+)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```

for replace url with links but it doesn't works with some symbols like # and so many other

and also i want that if the content appears like this

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/">http://www.abc.com/</a>
```

then the preg_replace skip this otherwise it will duplicate the same and produces wrong result.

Comment: This question gets asked a lot. Try searching for: "php linkify url"

Comment: Or if you're desperate: http://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just look for anything starting with http:// or https:// up until any whitespace character?

```
https?://[^\s]+
```

That is obviously pretty forgiving, the only problem is that you **might** get some false positives.

Answer (score 1):

The text helper class from Kohana has a function for this that would probably be a good starting point: https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/text.php#L362